# How to fix "Network Error at axios createError,Handle Error" in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i am using react native to build my application and every thing is going good so far but today when i start my app on android emulator , my app starts showing error :

> Network Error
>
> > - node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:24 in createError
> > - node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:81:25 in handleError
> > - ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

```
const fetchContacts = dispatch => async () => {
    try {
        const response = await ContactApi.get('/getContactsList');
        dispatch({ type: 'contact_list', payload: response.data.data })
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}


import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://example.com'
});
```

Comment: The problem might with the server rather than the client. Check if your server is active and successfully generating responses for the given endpoint.

Comment: Curious if you solved this? This comment suggests there might be a problem with the console.log line. https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960#issuecomment-309287911